# I am learning Ruby on rails and develpment sqlite3 file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The sqlite3 file is showing me that has a lot of rows and eight columns of numbers, can anyone help me and tell me what this numbers mean. I am using windows vista home, ruby 2.0.0, rails 4.0.2. If there is anything else that anyone needs please ask me.

```
5351 4c69 7465 2066 6f72 6d61 7420 3300
0400 0101 0040 2020 0000 000d 0000 000b
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0008 0000 0004
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 000d
```

and continues for a very long time.
This happen after I install device, however I did continue with the class.
I created migrations and pins but now that I try to check and see if the pins work I get 
the following.

```
irb(main):001:0> pin.first
NameError: undefined local variable or method `pin' for main:Object
from (irb):1
from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails /commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

irb(main):002:0>

I did try next:

```
$ rails console
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
irb(main):001:0> pin = Pin.first
Pin Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "pins".* FROM "pins" ORDER BY "pins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Pin id: 2, description: "mypin", created_at: "2014-09-29 21:04:24",updated_at:    
"2014-09-29 21:04:24", user_id: nil>
irb(main):002:0> pin.user
=> nil
irb(main):003:0>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`Pin` should have an uppercase `P`. Try `Pin.first`.

Also, don't worry about what the `sqlite3` file has in it - you don't need to be able to read that file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You've already received an answer on the `Pin.first` issue.

Let's move to the sqlite file.
It's a binary file, so opening it as a text file will just show its contents, as hexadecimal numbers.

You might want to open it with a sqlite viewer. For example, this Firefox extension is easy to use: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/